# Why is my ssh output hanging until I kit a key

Tags: ssh, mac, terminal

I'm suddenly seeing strange behavior in all of my ssh sessions.

The output often freezes mid-stream until I hit a key. It's not on page boundaries, or any byte boundaries that I can see. It manifests itself most often with commands with large input, but sometimes only a few bytes of input will cause it.

Hitting a key will result in more output of the session. Sometimes it even "freezes" when waiting for a simple command to return, even if it wouldn't result in much output.

The output is not being buffered locally. I've monitored the network, and my client isn't getting the data until I press a key, which seems to "wake it up".

This is not a result of the connection going idle. It happens even on a very active connection in which I'm typing numerous commands.

After doing a lot of Googling, it looked like this might be an MTU issue. I did recently change DSL modems here on Fastweb in Italy, so the new modem might be the culprit, but the old modem no longer works, so it's hard to test. I tried changing my MTU to be lower (as low as 1280, which is all the Mac Wireless settings let me do). That does not appear to make any difference.

This happens will all ssh sessions on different servers.

I have not tried a different network yet, and am hoping there is something else I can try to get this to work.

Details: Mac, standard ssh, no local custom ssh configuration performed.

Comment: What does your network admin say about the problem?

Comment: Network admin? I think I might be the network admin in this case. :) This is happening when I ssh into boxes from my home network.

Comment: Do you have enough access to the modem to see if it has a MTU setting?

Comment: Don't take this the wrong way, but home questions are explicitly off-topic for SF, as [our help page](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic) makes very clear.

Comment: Have you found something?

Comment: @mike-gleason-jr-couturier, Unfortunately, I don't recall what I did, but I am pretty dang sure it was an issue with the modem or cruddy FastWeb network I was on at the time. I am sorry I can't be of more help! Honestly, I should probably delete this question at this point. Are you running into the same thing?

Comment: @Taytay Yes running into this issue at one office I'm working at.. nowhere else so I suspect also the provider. Thanks for all the infos!